# Getting user's card information in express checkout response

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I'm new to Paypal developments and i need to keep track on customers' `credit card information such card number,cvv`. but `response from express checkout does not contain any of it`. Is that the normal behaviour of EC since it's more like `guest checkout` OR am i getting irrelevant response.

Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE**

Paypal **EXPRESS CHECKOUT** does not return card info!!

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal behavior of express checkout or any other payment gateway integration. You would not be able to get any of those data as that data is classified as sensitive information. Do remember that storing a credit card number is risky and may get you a hard time to comply with PCI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But there are PGs who return credit card information such as card number, holder name. For example: *Eway* (https://www.eway.com.au/). However i found it that Paypal EC does not return those info.

Comment: @ROXY That is not a standard practice. It's likely to disappear over the next few years, as PCI merchant requirements tighten.

Comment: @duskwuff Thank you very much